# Stop the progress bar which is set as ActionView in Action Bar appcompat

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-appcompat

Hello I am having action bar which I made using appcompat library in android. It looks like

[image]

When I click on the refresh menu item then I here show the progress bar and it is displaying perfectly

```
menuItem.setActionView(R.layout.progressbar);
menuItem.expandActionView();
```

[image]

progressbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ProgressBar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</ProgressBar>
```

but after my task done in async task I am doing to stop it in `onPostExecute` like below which is not working, means progress bar still executing after that also. I want to hide it and show refresh button after this process complete but it is not working currently

```
menuItem.collapseActionView();
menuItem.setActionView(null);
```

Any idea what it is wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can guess, you've forgot to invalidate action bar. If you, then just call `invalidateOptionsMenu()` . And see the magic ;)

```
menuItem.collapseActionView();
menuItem.setActionView(null);
YourActivity.this.invalidateOptionsMenu();
```